# OpenCV OCR could not detect properly if the capcha letter is inter-connected

Tags: python, ocr, opencv

Original Image:

[image]

Then I turned the image to have a better image clarity:
[image]

However, I found that the OpenCV returned wrongly as I discover the letter 'U' & 'B' are inter-connected.

May I know if I can solve this problem?

Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: I might just be daft here but I don't quite understand what your problem is here. They look connected in the original and inverted? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is characters being inter-connected.
I understand you want to recognize the captcha by applying binary inverse threshold operation, but the issue is the way the each character is being represented. For instance `B` and `8` can't be recognized by `pytesseract` you need to [train](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/TrainingTesseract-4.00.html) for the current character representation.

Even if you separate each character and apply [erosion](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| U | e | J | 4 |

`B` and `8` can't be recognized correctly, in the current state.

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("input.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
start = 0
end = int(w/4)

for _ in range(0, 4):
    cropped = gry[0:h, start:end]
    start = end
    end = start + int(w/4)
    erd = cv2.erode(cropped, None, iterations=1)
    txt = image_to_string(erd, config="--psm 6")
    print([character for character in txt if character.isalnum()][0])
    cv2.imshow("erd", erd)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```